# Insert object into array

Tags: php, arrays, object, array-splice

i have an array in php full of "Eventos Calendario" objects, at some point in my script i need to introduce a new object of the same type at position x of this array. this is the code i am using

```
$EventoLimite = new EventosCalendario(null,$Timestamp, $TipoEvento);                
var_dump($EventoLimite);
array_splice($this->EventosEntrada, $i, 0, $EventoLimite); //
var_dump($this->EventosEntrada[$i]);
```

And the "Var_Dumps" i am getting are:

```
object(EventosCalendario)[15]
  public 'FechaHora' => int 1376334000
  public 'FechaHoraOriginal' => null
  public 'Tipo' => string 'Entrada' (length=7)
  public 'Origen' => string 'Insertado' (length=9)
  public 'Subtipo' => null
  public 'ID' => null

int 1376334000
```

Why is the new slot in the array only getting the value of "FechaHora" property? i need to get the whole object in $this->EventosEntrada[$i]. how can i do that??

Comment: From the `array_splice` docs: "*Note: If replacement is not an array, it will be typecast to one (i.e. (array) $parameter). This may result in unexpected behavior when using an object or NULL replacement.*". Maybe there is the problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "replacement" argument *must* be an array itself, so you should write

```
array_splice($this->EventosEntrada, $i, 0, [$EventoLimite]); // note []s
```

Comment: OH GOD you're a genius. Do the bracket means it's an array slot?

Comment: @user1181589: I just go to the docs whenever something unexpected happens :-)

Comment: life saving solution dude.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its because of that when you  introduce a new object, just public variables and functions are available in the specific file you work on. I mean it is cause by access of clsasses.